# How to use "value of variable" as class name ( to create an object in ObjectiveC)?

Tags: objective-c

I have a problem :

I want to use the value of a variable to create an object .

For example , I have a variable `myVar`.

```
If myVar == 'Client' :  myVar* obj (obj will be an Client instance)
If myVar == 'People' :  myVar* obj (obj will be an People instance)
```

Someone can help me ? (sorry for my english)

Comment: as you are comparing myVar with `Client`. why not to use conditional creation of your `obj`.

Comment: no i don't compare , it's for the explanation: I have a function with a string in parameter. I want create an object using the value of my string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would use `NSClassFromString(@"ClassName")` to get the class from a string. To get an instance of the class, you would call `alloc` and `init`. For example:

```
NSString *myString = [NSClassFromString(@"NSString") alloc] init];
```

If you aren't sure which class you're going to be passing to `NSClassFromString`, or if you want to pass in different variables, you can use the type `id`, like so:

```
id myObject = [NSClassFromString(myVar) alloc] init];
```

You may have to typecast `myObject` later on, or reassign it to a typed variable, if you want Xcode to support code completion for that class' properties and methods.

You can [read more about NSClassFromString in the developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSClassFromString).

**Edit:**

Since there's some other discussion going on here about runtime introspection and the "fragile" nature of this code, I'll explain a bit more. The Objective-C runtime supports all kinds of neat tricks, including instantiating classes from strings. Of course you have to be sure that you get back the kind of object that you were expecting in the first place.

The first thing to check after instantiating an object from a class returned by NSClassFromString is if the object is `nil`. If it is, something went wrong between NSClassFromString and alloc, or between alloc and init. I'd bet your string isn't actually an existing class. So, a slightly safer way to do this is like so:

```
id myObject = nil;   // Declare a myObject variable. Initialize to nil
Class class = NClassFromString(myVar);

if(!class) 
{ 
  // The class doesn't exist, we can't make the object
}
else 
{
   myObject = [[class alloc] init]; // You can also use [class new] if you're using a vanilla initializer

  if(!myObject) 
  {
     // myObject couldn't be created for some reason...
  }
  else
  {
    // You've got an instance of your class
  }
}
```

I'd like to take this a step further though, because the runtime is awesome.

You can also check if a given object can perform some method. To do so, take a look at `respondsToSelector:`. (Selector means "method name" and is essentially a string.) Assuming we've got a valid object inside of myObject, we can check if myObject can do some action, say, `show`.

```
if([myObject respondsToSelector:@selector(show)])
{
   [myObject show]; // Safe to call `show` here
}
else
{
   // Not safe, do something else!
}
```

I've passed `show` to `@selector` because it's a valid method, defined in `UIAlertView.h`. What if we weren't sure about our selector's existence? Well, we could create a selector from a string, just like we did with the class. Here's how that works:

```
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"myCustomMethod");

if ([myObject respondsToSelector:selector])
{
  [myObject performSelector:selector];
}
```

We create the selector, check if the object implements that method, and if it does, effectively call the method.

When I said that you should check that you got back the kind of object you were expecting, I forgot to mention that you can also ask the runtime if an object's class is equal to a given class. Here's an example of that:

```
id myObject = [[NSClassFromString(@"UIView") alloc] init];

if([myObject isKindOfClass:[UIView class]])
{
  // We've got a UIView. Set a frame, install it in a hierarchy, or have a drink with it.
}
else
{
  // Mayday!
}
```

More often then not, you'll want to be checking for specific behaviors rather than classes, but it may be useful to try to instantiate a `Class` and check if it worked. This helps when you're checking for backwards compatibility on older versions of iOS.

Hope this helps!

Comment: No...this wont create an instance.

Comment: he want of type Client, Bus, Car...not `NSString`.

Comment: He has mentioned Client and Person

Comment: +1 Corrects way is using `id` and `NSClassFromString`. You can't have typechecking since you really don't know what class you will get. To have typecheck, use simple `if-else` for each possible class.

Comment: @iMartin: That's good you need to check by if-else at 100's of place later in the code, but no introspection and correct class creation on top!!!

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Not sure what you mean by _“no introspection and correct class creation“_. Another thing is, that maybe `Client` is subclass of `Person` and if you _know_ you can allocate just these two, you can use `Person *` type.

Comment: Moshe's solution is completly correct in a dynamic typing language as Objective-C. If you do not like that, don't use Objective-C. If you want to restrict the classes (in 99 % you don't want, because it is quite clear, that there is no problem) you should not build a if cascade but use -containsObject (NSSet).

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad: You are pointing to me. If you can see, in the 3rd comment I mentioned id is good, but typechecking is required. And **Dont suggest anyone not to use Obj-C.** Its my view if you dont like, I am not forcing you to use.

Comment: @Moshe: That's perfect explanation.

Comment: I hope nobody's taking "fragile" too literally.  The worst that could happen is messaging the wrong class or just nil, both of which are avoidable.  What makes this "fragile" is the fact that the possibility of getting nil is too high to be worth going this route.  Now, if you used a few more runtime hacks and *created* the missing class...

Comment: one gotcha about this approach: choosing the correct initializer may require a good chunk of runtime type testing, and it can be difficult to be prepared for any case or assume that a standard initializer (e.g. `-init`) is also a designated initializer for the dynamic class. several types may not support `-init` (i.e. they need initialization parameters to be useful) although it is not required that they eliminate support of `-init` (or other designated initializers of their bases which they do not support).

Comment: Justin, I thought of this too, admittedly, which is why I shied away from using `UIAlertaview` in my later examples.

Comment: @Anoop type checking is in many situations simply wrong. Types are /not/ the only way to get save code, but in many situations complex to handle. And this /is/ the /nature/ of objective-c.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad: That is why i suggested another answer, which I delete. and i guess you are not able to see it now.